# What is failed closed switch?

Tags: switches, failure

What is the meaning of switch failed open or failed closed in electronics?
I did a search but without results.

Comment: "Failed closed" is a switch which remains ON leaving equipment powered when you switch it off. Can be quite startling...

Answer (score 9):

As I understand your question the answer would be this.

A `failed open` switch is a switching device (be it mechanical, relay, semiconductor) that has lost it's switching capabilities (it's defective) and the switched contacts are now constantly open (disconnected) regardless of the control signal to the switch.

Similarly a `failed closed` switch is the same just with the contacts connected through.

Comment: It could also be a switch that has not failed at all but has lost its input signal and went to the open (fail open) or closed (fail closed) position.

Comment: @scorpdaddy - could it? you mean like in control room of a chemical facility where the operator is unable to toggle an electrical line and it's unclear if the switch itself or anything between it and the operator has failed?   OR sth. like a defective WiFi switch for electrical outlets where the relay itself is still fine? I'd count the whole WiFi switch as a "switching device". Right now I can't imagine a scenario where one would mean something else when talking about a `failed open/closed switch` but the switching device/element itself.

Comment: Electrically controlled switches require an electrical signal to command the switch open/close.  The upstream device that sends that signal could lose its power supply.  Or the upstream device fails.  Then input signal goes away, and the switch goes to a default position, open or close.  The failure is not in the switch itself, but somewhere upstream.

Answer (score 1):

As you usually do not get a say in how physical devices like a toggle switch will fail, I am going to assume this is for active circuits, such as relays or transistors,

In these cases, I would consider it the "Fail-safe" state, e.g. if there is an error in the system, or even if it looses power, what state do the outputs change to,

So a fail closed contact pair might be a relays Normally closed contact pair, if the circuit looses power, the relay closes, and keeps something that should be powered in a failure state to keep things safe under all reasonable conditions. e.g. a cooling fan going to 100%,

Answer (score 0):

You typically encounter terms like this when doing safety calculations. For example, a relay supplying some actuator etc could be dangerous if the relay contacts get stuck in the closed (active) position, but safe if they get stuck in the open (inactive) position.

So when you do theoretical calculations of how long the relay supposedly lasts before it fails in a dangerous way, you only need to consider the cases where it gets stuck in the dangerous position.

Answer (score 0):

The terms 'switch failed open' and 'switch failed closed' may be applicable to any type of switch whether mechanical, magnetic, electromagnetic, mercury, vacuum tube or semiconductor.

A switch is said to have 'failed open' when continuity between its terminals cannot be established when actuated.

A switch is said to have 'failed closed' when continuity between its terminals cannot be broken when actuated.